# Explicit constructor in array of objects

Tags: c++11

```
struct Row
{
  Row() { puts("default"); }
  Row(const Row &other) { puts("copy"); }
  Row(Row &&other) { puts("move"); }
  explicit Row(int) { puts("conv. c'tor"); }  
};

int main()
{

  Row rs;   
  Row r[3] = {1, 3, rs};

  Row r3[3]{1, 3, rs}; // no conversion exists 

}
```

I know explicit constructor is not a candidate for copy initialization. But, How come when direct initializing results in error?

And also How array of objects allocated in memory? Is it same like array of scalar types?
If I turn off elide constructors flag and remove explicit keyword, I get conv, move, conv, move and copy in first and also the same in second? can someone explain that?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Yes, if you make the conversion constructor explicit, trying implicit conversion (as in `Row r[3] = {1, 3};`) results in an error. The other question doesn't seem to have anything to do with the first. It should probably be in a question of its own.

Comment: The question is does aggregate initialization has the same effect as copy initialization when initializing array of objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[C++11 dcl.init#14](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/dcl.init#14)

> The initialization that occurs in the form
> T x = a;
> as well as in argument passing, function return, throwing an exception ([except.throw]), handling an exception ([except.handle]), and aggregate member initialization  ([dcl.init.aggr]) is called copy-initialization.

Aggregate member initialization is copy-initialization, not direct-initialization.